# Saving formatted data separated by vertical bars(pipe-delimited) to a file in Python

Tags: python, file

```
    # Get the filepath from the command line
import sys
F1= sys.argv[1] 
F2= sys.argv[2]



"""load the two files for processing"""
action_log=[]
#open first file
with open(F1, 'r') as accounts_file:
  main_log = accounts_file.read().splitlines()
  split_main_log = [word.split('|') for word in main_log]

#open second file
with open(F2, 'r') as command_file:
  command_log = command_file.read().splitlines()
  split_command_file = [word.split('|') for word in command_log]


for i in range(0, len(split_command_file)):
  if (split_main_log[i][1] == split_command_file[i][3] and split_command_file[i][0] == 'sub'):
    if split_main_log[i][2] >= split_command_file[i][1]:
      split_main_log[i][2] = int(split_main_log[i][2]) - int(split_command_file[i][1])
  elif split_main_log[i][1] == split_command_file[i][3] and split_command_file[i][0] == 'add':
    split_main_log[i][2] = int(split_main_log[i][2]) + int(split_command_file[i][1])

    for i in range(0,len(split_main_log)):
      split_main_log[i] = str(split_main_log[i])


for i in range(0,len(split_main_log)):
  split_main_log[i]='|'.join(split_main_log[i])
output_new = ""
output_new = "\n".join(split_main_log)



 out_file = open(F1,'w') #openfile
 out_file.write(output_new)
```

I am unsure of why my output has so many vertical bars. I'm just overlooking something and need another eye on it (been at it for a few hours). Any help would be awesome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inserts `|` between each character because it passes a `str` as an argument to `join`. The `str.join` method takes a sequence as an argument and returns a `str` which is each element of the sequence separated by the instance which called `join`. You may demonstrate this for yourself by running `'|'.join('foobarbaz')`.

You can start by removing this cast to `str`:

```py
    for i in range(0,len(split_main_log)):
      split_main_log[i] = str(split_main_log[i])
```

This will likely break the `str.join` call since you're casting the values to `int` in the parent `for` loop. You'll need to cast those values to `str` after you're done with the arithmetic, like this:

```py
for i in range(0, len(split_command_file)):
  if (split_main_log[i][1] == split_command_file[i][3] and split_command_file[i][0] == 'sub'):
    if split_main_log[i][2] >= split_command_file[i][1]:
      split_main_log[i][2] = str(int(split_main_log[i][2]) - int(split_command_file[i][1]))
  elif split_main_log[i][1] == split_command_file[i][3] and split_command_file[i][0] == 'add':
    split_main_log[i][2] = str(int(split_main_log[i][2]) + int(split_command_file[i][1]))
```

Please provide a minimum reproducible sample and I can help more. It's difficult to debug this without the input files.

Comment: Sir, thanks so much for the help. Works perfectly. Just an over sight on my part. Definitely a learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

How about using csv? and simply telling csv writer to use pipe sign as delimiter?

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        csv_writer.writerow(["ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3"])
        for i in listOfDictionary:
            csv_writer.writerow([i["key1"], i["key2"], i["key3"]])
```